# Cassandra DB. com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table person

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

[The keyspace and 'person' table are exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ircNZ.png)

Hello, I'm new with Cassandra, so I'm just trying to execute select query from my java code, but I got an exception that the table is not exist (but it exists. Check the link above).
Please help me figure out what could be a cause of this problem.
Thank you in advance.

```
public class DS_Cassandra implements DS 
{
    Cluster cluster;
    Session session;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( DS_Cassandra.class.getName() );

    public DS_Cassandra() 
    {
        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
        session = cluster.connect("testing");
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Person> read() 
    {
        ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM person"); //and here exception happened



2016-03-02 22:06:26 INFO  NettyUtil:83 - Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
2016-03-02 22:06:26 INFO  DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy:95 - Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
2016-03-02 22:06:26 INFO  Cluster:1475 - New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table person
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:63)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:39)...
```

Comment: Table names are case sensitive - Person and person are not the same table.

Comment: Resolved. Thank you. It was epic fail from my side.

Comment: @YakivBondar can you please clarify what was the epic fail? I am also seing this error somewhere else I your information could be helpful.

Comment: See @JeffJirsa comment. Table names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding your keyspace names with the table name.

For your case: "SELECT * FROM my_keyspace_name.person"